# How to create a query in MS Access that allows you to sum each customers total cost?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need to be able to sum each customer's expenses to get a total bill for them. If that bill is less that a certain number (let's say $3000), then it should not be included in my report. How would I go about writing this? The costs are stored in a column called "Rate" and the customers names are stored in the columns "FirstName" and "LastName" and each customer has a CustomerID. I am thinking something along the lines of

> (sum of rates Where CustomerID is the same) >= 3000

So for example sum all rates when the CustomerID is 1, 2, 3, etc.
That was my attempt at pseudocode as I'm new to Access and don't quite know the syntax yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest learning basic skills before attempting actual work.  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: This will get you started: http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut04.htm  Then on the report you create, you can edit the query within that report to only show Expenses >= 3000

Comment: You'll need to `SUM(Rate)`, `Group By (Other fields that aren't summed)` and ensure the `SUM(Rate)` is `Having` a total greater than 3000 - think that mentions all the keywords you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Sum(Rate) As Expenses
From [TableName]
Group By CustomerID, FirstName, LastName
Having Sum(Rate) >= 3000
```